# Jumping Vs. Gravity

Tags: xna, c#, physics

Hi i'm working on my first XNA 2D game and I have a little problem.
If I jump, my sprite jumps but does not fall down.
And I also have another problem, the user can hold *spacebar* to jump as high as he wants and I don't know how to keep him from doing that. Here's my code:
The Jump :

```
    if (FaKeyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        {
            Jumping = true;
            xPosition -= new Vector2(0, 5);
        }

        if (xPosition.Y >= 10)
        {
            Jumping = false;
            Grounded = false;
        }
```

The really simple basic Gravity:

```
    if (!Grounded && !Jumping)
        {
            xPosition += new Vector2(1, 3) * speed;
        }
```

Here's where's the grounded is set to True or False with a Collision

```
    Rectangle MegamanRectangle = new Rectangle((int)xPosition.X, (int)xPosition.Y, FrameSizeDraw.X, FrameSizeDraw.Y);
        Rectangle Block1Rectangle = new Rectangle((int)0, (int)73, Block1.Width, Block1.Height);
        Rectangle Block2Rectangle = new Rectangle((int)500, (int)73, Block2.Width, Block2.Height);

        if ((MegamanRectangle.Intersects(Block1Rectangle) || (MegamanRectangle.Intersects(Block2Rectangle))))
        {
            Grounded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Grounded = false;
        }
```

The grounded bool and The gravity have been tested and are working.
Any ideas why?
Thanks in advance and don't hesitate to ask if you need another Part of the Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I'm not very good at XNA, but if I had to guess, the following would be your issue (unless I'm misunderstanding your code):

```
if (FaKeyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
{
    Jumping = true;
    xPosition -= new Vector2(0, 5); // This Line
}
```

You are changing the position, even if `Jumping` should be false again. You'll want to check if `Jumping` is false after you've  checked if they should still be jumping, and then apply the vector. You'll probably also want another variable to see if they have already jumped as high as you allow. Let's call it `Falling`. You could also do it a single if statement. Something like:

```
if (FaKeyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) &&
        (Grounded || (!Falling && xPosition.Y < 10)))
{
    Jumping = true;
}
if (xPosition.Y >= 10) {
    Jumping = false;
    Falling = true;
}
```

And then, when you are `Grounded`, you'll want to set `Falling = false` again.

At least, that's my hunch.

Comment: How could I make this check?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Updated my answer. Hopefully that helps :)

Comment: One last little thing, in your example how would you define Falling?

Comment: ooh, my C# is rusty, but if I remember correctly, it would be `bool Falling = false;`. The same way you do `Jumping` basically

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this:

```
if (FaKeyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space)) 
    { 
        Jumping = true;
         xPosition -= new Vector2(0, 5);
    }
```

To this:

```
if (FaKeyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && Jumping == false) 
    {
         Jumping = true;
         xPosition -= new Vector2(0, 5);
    }
```

Woops, nevermind.  Got ninja'd.